# Как исправить тормоза openSuse 12.1?

Tags: opensuse, оптимизация, производительность

В принципе, железо позволяет, и не должна система тормозить: pentium D, nvidia 7950. Но очень часто начинает жутко тормозить, особенно при копировании на флешку. Дрова - установленные, swap отдельным диском 4гб. Как оптимизировать, в чем могут быть проблемы?

Comment: вывод команды top покажите вовремя тормозов

Comment: Та же самая проблема. Железо позволяет. Но на флешку fat 32 скопировать видео 1.3 GB нужно 15-20 мин.

Answer (score 1):

поменяй шедуллер, как это сделать посмотри [тут](http://www.opennet.ru/base/sys/linux_shedulers.txt.html). Вроде как тормозит система меньше и минимальна скорость копирования у меня не менее 6 мб/сек.

Answer (score 0):

Раздел, с которого копируешь, не ntfs какой-нибудь? А то я замечал, что при обращении к ntfs, создаётся неслабая такая нагрузка на процессор.

Comment: в основном копирую с/на флешку,естественно у нее фат32,top показывает что именно грузит mount